# How to edit application descriptor in Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I am trying to migrate my AIR mobile project from FlashDevelop to Adobe Flash Builder 4.7. In FlashDevelop I have my AIR application descriptor application.xml. When I created a new Flash Builder project it generated a new application descriptor (Mail-app.xml) in the /src folder, and put it into /bin-debug. However, when I try and copy the configuration from my old application descriptor to the new one, the Main-app.xml in the /bin-debug folder remains the same. I tried cleaning project, but it immediately recreates some sort of default application descriptor in /bin-debug. Where and what should I change so the changes will be picked by Flash Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an application descriptor in your `src` folder. That is the one you make changes to. The one in `bin-debug` is a generated copy of that one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My problem was I did not realize the application descriptor goes in the same folder in the package structure as the main application file. My main file was deep in the package, and I missed the generated application descriptor there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Flash Builder puts the generated application descriptor in the same folder as the main application file. When I created the project, the descriptor was created in the root, as the generated Main.as went to the default package. However, when I copied my source file, the main application file was in a com.mycompany.myproject package; so, Flash Builder generated the new application descriptor and put it there, and I missed it. Problem solved.